# Low efficiency buck converter

Tags: mosfet, dc-dc-converter, buck, efficiency, switching-losses

I've seen the circuit below on YouTube.
But it has low efficiency and the p-chnnel MOSFET gets hotter as the output & input voltage difference increases (it goes above 100c with heatsink).
I don't have a true-rms current meter, but my meter shows a constant input current even if I double or triple the input voltage (without changing the output voltage & cuttent).

Can anybody help me increase the efficiency please? (Unfortunately I don't have an osiloskop, but what causes this switching loss?)

Or if you think this circuit is not practical suggest me another one. (I couldn't find by googling)
[image: buck-converter lm2596]
[image: layout]

Comment: Help you do what?

Comment: What differences do you have? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rMwN4x2q69A

Comment: Does it oscillate at all? How it's built? Pulse circuits are very critical, they suffer badly if there's too long wires or missing decoupling capacitors. The inductor must not saturate. How did you verify its not saturated? I am very suspicious how the drive circuit of the mosfet can make state changes fast enough for acceptable efficiency. You should have an oscilloscope and pulse circuit measuring skills for debugging. Do you have? BTW I wouldn't believe youtube videos. I would try to simulate the circuit or at least the extenal switch and its drive circuit.

Comment: 12-40V in 13,8V out,  impossible.

Comment: more than 20V in is possibly going to damage the MOSFET.

Comment: I hope that's actually a 12mm toroid, not 1.2mm

Comment: Tony Stewart Sunnyskyguy EE75, I replaced 2sd438 transistor with 2sc2383, other things are the same

Comment: @JYelton help me increase the efficiency!

Comment: Which MOSFET are you using? What values are the output capacitors? Why is the schematic so fuzzy? Please provide a sharp clear photo of the build.

Comment: Please draw a clean schematic. Click on edit and the schematic symbol.

Comment: Also, show your layout.

Comment: Wrong method for driving the PMOS. Most likely the PMOS cannot be turned on and off properly. This leads a high Rds which results in high dissipation and high junction temperature.

Comment: @MNasr:  Is there some reason you aren't using the circuit from the [datasheet?](https://www.ti.com/lit/gpn/lm2596)  It has a maximum output current of 3A, and accepts up to 40V input.  See the schematic in figure 35 on page 27.

Comment: @Rohat-Kılıç would you please help me with the correct method?!

Comment: @JRE I need more than 3A